# How to modify data from $.ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two .html, content.html and footer.html.

content.html

```html
<div>
   <div class="footer-content"></div>
</div>
```

footer.html

```html
<div>copyright</div>
```

i made a ajax call for content.html, then i want to append the footer.html to the data(content), before showing it.

i have tried this.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "filecheck.php", // Your server-side script
  data: { file: filePath }, // Pass the file path to the server-side script
  dataType: "html",
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    if (data === "error") {
      // If the server returns an error, redirect to 404
      window.location.href = "pages/404.html";
      return false;
    } else {
      // If the file exists, load the content
      console.log(data);
      if ($(data).find(".footer-content").length > 0) {
        // Load footer using AJAX
        console.log("put foote");
        $.ajax({
          url: "elements/footer.html",
          success: function (footer) {
            console.log("ok foot!");
            $(data).find(".footer-content").append(footer);
            //$(data)$('.footer-content', data).html(footer);
          },
        });
      }

      $("#content").html(data);
    }
  },
});
```

this code doesnt seem to work:

```js
$(data).find('.footer-content').append(footer);
```

footer data wasn't added to .footer-content

Comment: so... `data` is a string, each time you are "appending" to it, you're actually appending to a dom fragment that you created with `$(data)`, which doesn't update `data`. then, you didn't store that result... so it just gets thrown away before you recreate another dom fragment based on `data` again.

Comment: Where is `content.html` in the code? I only see `filecheck.php` and `footer.html`.

Comment: @Barmar part of the response from `filecheck.php` I assume

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @Barmar i didnt include the filecheck.php as it is not neccesary. it only check if the file exist. content.html and footer.html is provided.

Comment: But the code never tries to download `content.html`, that's what's missing.

Comment: @barmar filePath = "content.html". i forgot to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue of timing.

The second `$.ajax()` success callback completes *after* `$("#content").html(data)` is executed. jQuery's `.html()` method sets string data via `.innerHTML` and won't keep a reference to the `$(data)` document fragment; adding elements to `data` later will have no effect on the DOM.

The solution is to set your HTML data then find the relevant element within `#content`. If it exists, you can load extra HTML into it.

```js
$("#content")
  .html(data)
  .find(".footer-content")
  .load("elements/footer.html");
```

The [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method will only run if the selector finds an element.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I wasted almost 2 hours looking for the solution.

Comment: Related/additional details: `$(data).find(".footer-content").append(footer);` will append `footer` only to that specific *in-memory* jquery object representation of `data`.  After that line executes, the in-memory version will be cleared if it's not stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code that works.

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'filecheck.php', // Your server-side script
            data: { file: filePath }, // Pass the file path to the server-side script
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {

                if (data === 'error') {
                    // If the server returns an error, redirect to 404
                    window.location.href = 'pages/404.html';
                    return false;
                } else {
                    // If the file exists, load the content
                    $('html').removeClass('lock');

                    if ($(data).find('.footer-content').length > 0) {
                        $("#content")
                          .html(data)
                          .find(".footer-content")
                          .load("elements/footer.html");
                    }else {
                            $('#content').html(data);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
    });
```